# Export-Mailbox Error

Tags: exchange-2007

All, I am using export-mailbox to move some data and it is working fine until I get this error:

StatusMessage                    : Error occurred in the step: Moving messages.
                                    Failed to copy messages to the destination
                                   mailbox store with error:
                                   MAPI or an unspecified service provider.
                                   ID no: 00000000-0000-00000000

This is the command I am using:

export-mailbox -identity mailboxA -targetmailbox mailboxB -targetfolder folderA -allowmerge

We are on SP2 and I am running this under an account that is not a domain or enterprise admin. THe account has Exchange Server Administrator Permission Both Source and Target Exchange Mailbox Server. THe account is part of the Local Administrators Group Member Both Source and Target Exchange Mailbox Server. This account has Full Access permission on both the target and source servers. THe issue happens at any time and I am only trying to run this on one mailbox, the only mailbox I need to run it on. THe event log is "Error   Exchange Migration   Export Mailbox     Event 1008". The log under migration logs just shows that it was running okay then it gives the same error as above "Error was found for mailboxA (mailboxa@domain.com) because: Error occurred in the step: Moving messages. Failed to copy messages to the destination mailbox store with error: 
MAPI or an unspecified service provider.
ID no: 00000000-0000-00000000, error code: -1056749164"

Any ideas on what to do/try?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thank you for your help. I have figured it out by using the -includefolders parameter and running this for each top-level folder. By doing this I was able to copy over every top-level folder plus each folders subfolders. In all I had 9 top-level folders that errored out (the above mentioned error) so now I will drill down in each of those folders running the -includefolders until I finally hit the exact folder that is giving me the error. Doing it this way allows me to copy over all of the data AND to find out exactly which subfolder is giving me the error.